# Google Analytics Goal

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I have a specific problem using Google Analytics. I want to fire a Goal after a user is visiting `/general/danke.php`. I implemented the code to every page on my site. The destination is set to `/general/danke.php` and I chose the option `Equals to:`. It does not work I even read the article and I think I tried everything in this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033158?hl=en.
It does not seem to work. When I am running the site it shows 1 user so the tracking seems to work. When I set the Page to `/`it shows a 100% conversion rate.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your goal configuration? Also, check that you don't have fillets that modify the page path.

Comment: Filters..... Thanks autocorrect